How do I use cURL to submit this form and get the resulting data?
There's a form here which when submitted will return a .dat file (which is just a text file in this case) when the "Dst Output" button is selected with either of the two subselects to it (I'm using "IAGA2002-like format"). The various "Start Year" and "End Year" fields must also be filled in (weird form, I know). I've looked over a lot of different posts and answers about how to use cURL with forms, but I struggle to understand how it would actually work for a form like this; I imagine it can't be that complicated.

Open your browser's network tab when submitting the form and see what values are actually being sent. Most browsers will actually let you use a 'copy as curl' feature that gives you a complete curl command.

@Evert: Thanks, that worked great for generating the cURL command; the second part of the problem is getting the data, as it's not returned directly in the response, but instead a webpage is returned with a link inside of it (here in this particular case of running it right now, but the .dat file generated is different each time); in browsers this seems to automatically redirect to the text file, but is there any way to get it directly from cURL, or do I have to combine it with something else?

Do it with something else.

@Evert: Actually, simply appending the -L flag for the redirect worked perfectly! Thanks for the help, I'll write up an answer to my own question referencing that and your suggestion.

Ah that makes sense. You said the link was encoded as HTML and that would not have worked

I found out how to do this, partially based on a suggestion in a comment to the question itself and my own findings from a search.
Using Chromium I opened the DevTools and went to the network tab, and then I submitted the form on the site, which appeared as a request there; I right-clicked it and chose Copy -> Copy as cURL. This gave my a working cURL command to use, although I found that I could safely delete all the headers containing browser data and so on without impacting anything.
It returned a small HTML page with a link in it that was automatically redirected to, so I used the -L flag in the cURL command, and got exactly the output I wanted. Lastly I simply appended -o filename.txt to save it to a text file with a filename of choice.
So ultimately, the command I used was as follows:
curl -L 'https://wdc.kugi.kyoto-u.ac.jp/cgi-bin/dstae-cgi?SCent=20&STens=1&SYear=5&SMonth=01&ECent=20&ETens=2&EYear=9&EMonth=12&Image+Type=GIF&COLOR=COLOR&AE+Sensitivity=0&Dst+Sensitivity=0&Output=DST&Out+format=IAGA2002' -o filename.txt
